# Running makemigrations in Django package test case with tox

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a Django package, and I want to run `makemigrations --check --dry-run --noinput` in a test case (not using pytest; standard Django test runner). I tried just running `call_command`, but, with sqlite, that in turn uses the in memory db. So if there was supposed to be a migration, the db/django wouldn't know about it. I.e., when I do this, the command just says that no changes were detected.

If you try doing `django-admin makemigrations`, you'll get an "apps not loaded" issue. Anyone have an idea of what we can try to do? Maybe threads? Ref this is taking place in django-oauth-toolkit

Comment: What are you actually trying to test? Generally that isn't something that would be tested.

Comment: For the last two minor Django versions, 3.2 and 4.0, I’ve had users create migration file and migrate on production. I’d like to avoid those situations by finding all potential migration files before a Django is released.